# Trying to solve a linear PDE... I thought it was simple

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes

I have a PDE of the following form, from a physics problem:
$$
y \left(\alpha \frac{\partial }{\partial y}+x \frac{\partial^2 }{\partial x \partial y} \right)f(x,y) = \left( z_1 + z_2 x^\alpha y^{-2} \right) f(x,y)
$$
$f(x,y)$ is a real-space real-valued function and 
$z_{1,2},\alpha$ are real numbers, generally irrational.   The latter, specifically the $z_2$ coefficient term, seems to make all of the textbook methods (characteristics, Froebnius, Fourier transform) fail.   Does any one know weather a method exists to solve this?  Apologies if this is a simple question but, well, I am a theoretical physicist and it is not simple for me.

Comment: What do you mean by "solve"? In what region, under what boundary conditions, or you want just one solution or all solutions? And what are your $z$ and $\alpha$?

Comment: Maybe change variables to $\xi = \log x$, $\eta = \log y$ and try Fourier transforms again.

Comment: Looks like a semilinear wave equation, so initial data should be prescribed on one of the two light rays.

Comment: Igor, thank you, in fact Froebnius might work with this variable change

Comment: Do you have an initial condition?  (and are you sure characteristics don't work?)

Answer (score 8):

The Ansatz 
$$f(x,y)=x^pu(x^\alpha y^{-2}) $$
 yields to a linear second order ODE for $u(t)$

$$2t^2 u''+ (4\alpha+2p)tu'+(z_1+z_2t)u=0\  , $$
which can be immediately solved by series in terms of hypergeometric functions.

Comment: Actually Bessel functions: $${t}^{1/2-\alpha-p/2}{{ J}_{\sqrt {4\,{\alpha}^{2}+4\,\alpha\,p+{p}^
{2}-4\,\alpha-2\,p-2\,z_{{1}}+1}}\left(\sqrt {2z_{{2}}
t}\right)}
$$ and the corresponding expression with $Y$ instead of $J$.

Comment: Thank you Pietro and Robert.  This really helps, sometimes the right trick overcomes months of thinking :((